# What cases "cannot convert "%d" (type untyped string) to type int" in Go?

Tags: arrays, go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func printArray(x [3]int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d", x[1]);
    // cannot convert "%d" (type untyped string) to type int
    // invalid operation: "%d" + v (mismatched types string and int)
    // for _, v := range x {
    //  fmt.Printf("%d" + v);
    // }
}

func main() {
    a := [3]int{1, 2, 3};

    for _, v := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%d\n", v);
    }

    printArray(a); 
}
```

I can successfully print the array in the go method, but when I pass array into the method, it throws an error when it tries to print. What cause's the method to treat it differently then main method?

Comment: What version of go are you using? It seems to work for me: https://play.golang.org/p/p4fFqro9W60

Comment: go1.10.3 is the version

Answer (score 2):

I see your error now. You are trying to concatenate or add the string and the int, instead of passing the two arguments to the function.

```
for _, v := range x {
   fmt.Printf("%d" + v); // The error is in this line
}
```

It should be:

```
func printArray(x [3]int) {
    for _, v := range x {
       fmt.Printf("%d", v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My Answer is not particularly related to this Question, But I had similar error and the way I solved is updating here, may be some future users may found helpful!

**Got the same error for below Code: Here `itemID` is `int`**

```
strSQL := "SELECT item_desc,item_sel_price FROM item_master WHERE item_id=" +  itemID)
```

**Solved by using `fmt.Sprintf`**

```
strSQL := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d","SELECT item_desc,item_sel_price FROM item_master WHERE item_id=", itemID)
```